# Any reason to take an Unchained angel eidolon, aside from fluff?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, summoner, eidolon

I've read through the subtypes. From what I've seen almost all subtypes have some sort of natural weaponry (aside from the angels, archons, ...).
Additionally most weaponry-like and damaging evolutions are only for demons, daemons, and proteans, and not for angels.

So I'm wondering, is there any reason for taking angels instead of any of the other types? Fluff aside, is there some rules-wise saving grace there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Angels have a few things going for them, but you're right that they're generally sub-par.**

*Advantage 1 - Resists*: Angels get more built-in resistances than any other subtype except demons (and if demon is an option for you, angel probably isn't).

*Advantage 2 - Alignment*: Angels can be chosen by pretty much any non-evil summoner. Agathaions and especially azatas are pickier about who they'll work for.

*Advantage 3 - Flight*: Flight is something just about every eidolon is going to want eventually (except possibly ranged weapon eidolons), and angels get it for free. Admittedly, so do azatas (angels' main competition in the eidolon subtype department), but it's still a reason to look down (literally) on most other subtypes.

Generally speaking, angels are the go-to choice for summoners who want an azata but either 1) aren't "ideologically pure" enough to recruit one, or 2) want to trade some damage potential for tankiness. Also, angels are still better than archons in almost all cases.

There are generally two optimal paths for building unchained eidolons: a weapon-wielding biped, or a pouncing quadruped (serpentine forms have some unique options but ultimately aren't as effective). Azatas are the undisputed champions in the biped category, but if for some reason you don't want or can't take an azata, an angel is one of the better remaining biped subtypes.

Comment: So if one is lawful and not after fluff or free wings devils would be a better choice there.  tnx

Comment: @ThomasE. Actually, I'd go with an angel over a devil. Devils get several useless skill buffs, and don't bring much to the table that angels don't. Azatas are the strongest choice for bipeds/weapon-wielders, with angels being one of the better also-rans in that category. For pouncey quadrupeds agathions, demons, and daemons are all pretty good, they just have different pros & cons. Since serpentine base form is pretty terrible, most of the other subtypes are overshadowed by the main 4 (azata, agathion, demon, daemon).

Comment: So weapon fighters angels would be good, for non weapon fighters the others?

Comment: @ThomasE. Yes. If you want a weapon-user eidolon then azata should be your first choice. If you can't take an azata or want something tankier then go with an angel (unless you expect to fight lots of incorporeal foes in which case the psychopomp pulls ahead). If you'd rather have an eidolon that uses natural attacks, then agathion, demon, and daemon are all strong choices (and air & fire elementals are worth looking at, if not quite top tier) depending on how well they fit your alignment and how well their individual quirks fit the campaign.

Comment: @ThomasE. Remember, biped form is for weapons, quadruped form is for natural attacks, and serpentine form is for potentially entertaining, but ultimately suboptimal, gimmicks. Your primary concern with subtypes should be which forms it can be and then how well its special abilities support those forms.